# Centos Can not boot

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

I have tried booting all images of centos normal and secure but does not boot as I have the following issue attached [image]

Comment: CentOS 7 features a relatively old kernel, you might want to try the 8th version.

Comment: actually I can not change he kernel version as I am not the admin I just want to reboot normally

Comment: Could you provide a little bit of context? What do you mean by "all Centos images"? How did you generate the above error?

Comment: I have the normal image shown and the secure image and the error you see in the image is generated once I choose either